# My laptop keyboard is not working properly

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, keyboard

My Compaq Presario laptop's keyboard is not working properly. When I start Windows XP normally, some keys don't work. When I start in Safe Mode, all my keys work properly.

Comment: Which Windows? Which laptop?

Comment: windows xp and lap is compaq presario

Answer (score 1):

What keys don't work specifically? And do they not work consistently?

You may have a driver issue, maybe and it is using the Windows default driver in safe mode, maybe some keyboard software gone amok, or you may have a virus.

You should check to see what keyboard driver you are using in your Device Manager (right click `My Computer>Manage>Device Manager>Keyboards`). It probably should say "Standard 101/102-Key or Microsoft Natural PS/2 Keyboard".

Check your `Control Panel>Add/Remove Programs` for any keyboard software. If you find it, figure out how to open and mange it, and see if you can set it back to the defaults. You can also use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) to see if any such software is starting.

Lastly, scan for viruses using [Malware Bytes](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html), [Superantispyware](http://download.cnet.com/SuperAntiSpyware-Free-Edition/3000-8022_4-10523889.html) and [Hitman Pro](http://download.cnet.com/Hitman-Pro-3-32-bit/3000-2239_4-10895604.html?tag=mncol;1).

Comment: Many keys doesn't work..
For example.. The keys 'a','i',F11,'+','Backspace',']'
These keys sometime works and sometime doesn't.sometimes these keys will be keep on pressing..i mean like this-(aaaaaaaaaaaaa)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem few days ago, but my problem was resolved when I formatted my computer.

If you don't have many important files on your computer, you could do the same, or scan for viruses as stated above.